# Can two threads write to different element of the same array?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I was wondering whether or not two threads could modify elements of the same array.

If I have `unsigned char array[4]`, can thread1 set `array[0]` and `array[1]` to 'A' and thread2 set `array[2]` and `array[3]` to 'B' at the same time without problems?

Comment: The same *absolute* memory location can be modified by more than one thread, always.

Comment: Since you're not setting any of the same address spaces, I don't think you'll run into any multithreading issues.

Comment: This depends on the architecture. What processor are you using?

Comment: @templatetypedef i7 6700k and an AMD on my other computer, i don't even know the model but it's 64  bits

Comment: There should not be any problem as long as same element is not being accessed at the same time by different thread.

Comment: @templatetypedef How could that depend on architecture?

Comment: @gbtimmon Imagine there's a processor that has word-level agreement across different cores about the state of memory. If one core writes to one byte of a word and another core writes to a different byte of the same word, it would be possible that neither one sees collectively what all the bytes in that word look like.

Comment: @templatetypedef Very interesting, thank you

Comment: @gbtimmon I'm actually not sure if any processor actually does this, though. Now I'm wondering if I'm just psyching myself out. :-)

Comment: Since my question seems to be answered, what should I do to "solve" the post ?

Comment: @templatetypedef you are talking about multi-core. The question is about multi threading. In multithreading, these could be only one core. Isn't it?

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/25697057/1025391

Comment: Usually it's reasonable to have some patience waiting for detailed answers. Maybe someone from another timezone would like to share their insights as well.

Comment: @MCG You can have multithreading on both a single-core or a multi-core machine, so again the answer would have to depend on the architecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By definition, a race condition happens when 1 or more threads write data to the same location in memory while others read from it (or write to it, too). Would multiple threads each modifying a different array element be writing to the same location in memory? The answer is no. Each array element has a region of memory reserved for it alone within the region attributed the overall array.  Modifications of different elements therefore do not write to any of the same memory locations.

Actually I asked this question a very long time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620183/scheduling-system-for-fitting), and based part of my PhD work on that. I fitted hundreds of curves (least-squares fitting) in parallel, while updating a single array that has the results by multiple threads.

Comment: Multiple writes to the same location can produce a data race by themselves, without any concurrent readers, by the standard's definition of "data race".  Other than that, although I think this answer is correct with respect to the question posed, its wording is very confusing.  Perhaps you mean to say "[...] for *different elements of* a single array"?

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right. However, I consider writing more demanding than reading, which is why if reading causes a race, then definitely writing does too (I corrected/improved my answer). I couldn't understand your suggestion. Please suggest an edit and I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I've actually made the edit I suggest.  By all means edit further or revert if you don't like it.  I hesitated to do this at first because it's a rather substantial change, but for that same reason, I don't know how to suggest such an edit any more compactly, given that my first attempt did not adequately convey my intent.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks. It's alright :)

Answer (score 3):

On all systems I have met it is not a functional problem to have different threads write to different elements of the same array. On some systems it may however be a performance problem due to threads on different cores accessing data in the same cache line. The HW will solve the functional part but performance may be bad.

The functional problem doesn't start until you want one thread to read data written by another thread. At that time you'll need a mechanism (e.g. mutex, semaphore, atomic operations, etc.) to ensure that written data is visible to all other threads.

Answer (score 2):

If the threads execute on the same core it will be a serial write process where you will set the different bytes just as 'linear' code would in one thread. However, you would not necessarily know in what order (in the normal case). Meaning what thread is executing in what order when.

However, if the writes occur from two different cores the cache line will be marked shared between the respective cores cache and the write operation will be announced using an RFO message. That will impact the performance.

So, in other words, keep writes to the same cache line in the same core as much as you can.

More information can be found here ->
[What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf)

/Anders